# Is there a __getattribute__ to get a class or object from a python module?

Tags: python, class

I have a string like this:

```
classname = "Recipe"
```

Now I have a module "contenttype.py" and I want to do something like this:

```
import contenttype
myobject = contenttype.__getobject__(classname)(param=value)
```

Is there something similar to **getattribute** to be used in module's top level?

I know I can do it with exec() but I am trying to avoid this.

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I found a way, but I am not convinced that it is good.

```
import inspect 
myobject = dict(inspect.getmembers(contenttype))[classname](param=value)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A module is just an object, so yes, you can use `__getattribute__` on it.

But you don't want to call `__getattribute__` directly, that's an implementation detail. For accessing named attributes on objects, including module members, use `getattr()`.

```
getattr(contenttype, classname)(param= value)
```

Comment: It's true that modules are usual objects but they don't really have `__getattribute__` method. (Try doing dir(module) and you'll see that.) And if you define it yourself it won't work. In spite of this built-in `getattr` function works as expected.